# On the decimal cycle length.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

"If $10$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, the repetend length is equal to $p − 1$... This result can be deduced from Fermat's little theorem, which states that $10^{p−1} = 1\pmod p$."

-[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Reciprocals_of_composite_integers_coprime_to_10)

How? I just don't see it. I'm not good at number theory.

Comment: When you type $10^{p-1}\equiv1$ mod $p$, with "mod" outside of the math tags, then you can get mismatches in fonts or worse.  Just type 10^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p, and you see $10^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$. (If there's more than one character after $\bmod$ to be included inside the parentheses, then you need braces, as in a\equiv b\pmod{34}, which gives you $a\equiv b\pmod{34}$.  Without the braces, only the $3$ will appear inside the parentheses.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The length of the period in the decimal expansion of $1/p$ is equal to the order $m$ of $10$ modulo $p$. This is because, then $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $10^m/p-1/p$ is an integer. The part about primitivity is simply saying that the order is exactly $m=p-1$. No proper factor will do.